# ‘max’ not meaningful for factors in R

Tags: r

```
getImportDate <- function(){
  hdfs.init()
  f <- hdfs.file("/user/rstudio/rdataecommerce4.csv","r")
  m <- hdfs.read(f)
  c <- rawToChar(m)
  data <- read.table(textConnection(c), header=TRUE , sep = ",")
  print(max(data$date, na.rm=TRUE))  //ERROR AT THIS LINE

}
```

I get the error:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 72L, 74L,  : ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
```

Why am I getting this error and How do I fix this?

Comment: whether @RHertel's or @lukeA's answer works depends on the structure of your data (which you haven't shown us).  What are typical values of the `date` column ... ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error?

You get this error because to are trying to get the maximum value of a variable of type factor, which does not make sense.

```
max(as.factor(49L))
# Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
#   ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
```

> How do I fix this?

Use a variable (maybe after type conversion) for which `max` makes sense:

```
max(as.Date("2016-01-01"))
# [1] "2016-01-01"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
print(max(as.numeric(as.character(data$date)), na.rm=TRUE))
```